# Detecting a number overflow in JavaScript at the time of base10 string conversion

Tags: javascript

The code evaluates `true` when the number string is within +/- 2^53 and false when it is outside of that range.

```
num_string = "9007199254740992"
new_num = (new Number(num_string)+"")
num_string === new_num
```

This seems to work, but what is the correct way to detect a number overflow?  This would fail, for example, if the initial string had leading zeros `007`.  This is not an overflow, that should not fail.

EDIT: I have to use a string, I'm converting to from a string to a number and want to know if my number got messed up.  So, I am testing a string (not a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a string:

```
9007199254740993 === 9007199254740992 // true
```

However, you should be checking against `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which will tell you the highest integer you can use without loss of precision.

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // 9007199254740991
```

So check against that:

```
if (num > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
  // not safe!
}
```

You can also use a function (credit to [`@RickHitchcock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150602/detecting-a-number-overflow-in-javascript-at-the-time-of-base10-string-conversio/29150649?noredirect=1#comment46523550_29150649)):

```
Number.isSafeInteger(num)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP want's this comparison to return `true`.

Comment: But I have to use a string...  I'll clarify... thanks

Comment: @jcalfee314: It doesn't matter where `num` comes from. The point is that you compare against `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. You said yourself you covert the string to a number. So what's prevents you from making this comparison?

Comment: Not happy with the first example, but +1 for `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: If the string is greater than 9007199254740992 then the Number I get from it is only 9007199254740992 .. so it will never be greater than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.  That is not ok, the user intended me to have a higher number.

Comment: @jcalfee314: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740991`. `9007199254740992` is **always** greater than `9007199254740991`. Also, not every number larger than `9007199254740991` results in `9007199254740992`: `12345678901234567890 // 12345678901234567000`.

Comment: For browsers that support `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you can use the `Number.isSafeInteger()` method instead:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

Comment: @Rick: Nice! I assumed `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` was part of ES5. Shame on me.

Comment: @jcalfee314: Again, what prevents you from converting the string to a number? You even claim that you are doing that already *"I'm converting to from a string to a number"*. Just pass the number. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: @jcalfee314: Why do you have to compare strings again? You have to provide more context to explain your situation better. Otherwise I think you are making this more complicated than it is. What is that you want to know through that operation? If you just want to know whether the string can be converted to a number, then this method will suffice. If leading zeros can be a problem, remove them first (I don't see how they can be a problem though, `Number('008')` works just fine and returns `8`).

Comment: @jcalfee314: It's really not clear what else you need besides `var canBeConverted = Number.isSafeInteger(Number(str));`.

Comment: It works great .. thank you.  I does not handle a decimal, however, I really need to use bigi for that, so I'll need to split it up on the decimal anyway.